# What are the advantages of Digest::SHA over Digest::SHA1?

Tags: perl, sha1, cpan, digest

Are there any advantages in using [Digest::SHA](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-SHA/lib/Digest/SHA.pm) over [Digest::SHA1](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-SHA1/SHA1.pm) or vice versa? both seem to be maintained but I don't see a reason for Digest::SHA1 to even exist with the existence of `Digest::SHA`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is none, `Digest::SHA1` is legacy, as is `SHA1`. Per the docs of `Digest::SHA1`:

> In 2005, security flaws were identified in SHA-1, namely that a possible mathematical weakness might exist, indicating that a stronger hash function would be desirable. The Digest::SHA module implements the stronger algorithms in the SHA family.

It clearly references `Digest::SHA`. The implementation in `Digest::SHA` is a bit faster than `Digest::SHA1` (per the docs of `Digest.pm` -- what you should probably be using anyway).

```
Algorithm      Size    Implementation                  MB/s
SHA-1          160     Digest::SHA v4.3.1              58.9
SHA-1          160     Digest::SHA1 v2.10              48.8
```

`Digest` is a factory for all modules in the `Digest` namespace, it prioritizes `Digest::SHA` over `Digest::SHA1`. You could even argue `Digest::SHA1` is twice over deprecated, as it was replaced by `Digest::SHA2`.

I believe it probably useful to substantiate the term "deprecated" here. I simply mean that `Digest::SHA1` isn't useful for non-SHA1 hashes that are still in the SHA family -- other distros can handle more.. Digest::SHA1 is also slower.. To the best of my knowledge it is still supported and has a stable release not all that long ago: *Digest-SHA1-2.13 - 03 Jul 2010 - Gisle Aas*

Comment: The ::SHA module included SHA-2 algorithms as well... but if you *are* still planning on using SHA-1 that's really not an argument one way other another. I looked at the docs and didn't see anything to suggest that Digest::SHA1 was legacy or deprecated.

Comment: @xenoterracid, Wrong, it is still an argument. Do you want to have both of them loaded in memory because some other module wishes to implement a hash in the same family that isn't SHA1? Do you want to depend on a different distribution with open bugs being maintained, when it only supports a subset of the functionality of the newer one -- and at that **it does it slower**...

Comment: That's a better argument ;) as opposed to talking about the security flaws which may or may not be relevant depending on what you're using it for.

Comment: Another big reason to pick `Digest::SHA` over `Digest::SHA1` is that the former is a core library (as of Perl 5.10.0), and the latter isn't (and never will be).

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that Digest::SHA1 is now dead. It was [removed from Debian Wheezy](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=594273), its package is no longer available. Other distros descending from Debian (e.g. Ubuntu) follow the same path.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff that was written to use `Digest::SHA1::sha1`, or which (in a fit of silliness) does `"Digest::$type"->new` instead of `Digest->new($type)` might need `Digest::SHA1`. Other than that, `Digest::SHA` is preferred, and it will be used by default for `Digest->new("SHA-1")`.